# qpython.sync() is returning a QProjection instead of the queried data

Tags: python, numpy, kdb, qpython

So I am running the following query without problems:

```
print(self.data_source.connections['history'].sync(
            '{[x;y;z]select from trade where date within(x;y), sym in z}',
            numpy.datetime64('2014-04-14', 'D'),
            numpy.datetime64('2017-08-14', 'D'),
            NumpyUtil.parse_symbols(['instr81', 'instr61', 'instr26'])
        ))
```

Here the `self.data_source.connections[]` is just a dictionary with the tickerplant, hdb and rdb connections and the `NumpyUtil.parse_symbols()` is a little method that parses the argument to the correct Numpy type (has been successfully tested).

The result it produces is the following and is as suspected:

```
[ ('2017-07-20', b'instr26', 31538122, b'instr14',  93.87083689,  77.0477359 , 81)
 ('2017-07-20', b'instr26', 31543119, b'instr72',  27.69372507,  80.00145357,  8)
 ('2017-07-20', b'instr26', 31678121, b'instr56',  58.24375362,  13.93626591, 36)
 ...,
 ('2017-07-26', b'instr81', 55344040, b'instr95',  18.75910878,  63.28561637, 98)
 ('2017-07-26', b'instr81', 81898858, b'instr78',  34.76710694,   8.32085477, 69)
 ('2017-07-26', b'instr81', 81938857, b'instr97',  64.54823106,   0.16524401, 81)]
```

Perfect :)

My problem arises when I put it into this wrapper method:

```
def synced_query(self, database, query, parameters):
    print(self.connections[database].sync(query, parameters))
```

When passing the *exact* same parameters, it returns something else, a QProjection:

```
QProjection(QLambda('{[x;y;z]select from trade where date within(x;y),sym in z}'), [numpy.datetime64('2012-06-20'), numpy.datetime64('2017-07-30'), QList([b'instr81', b'instr61', b'instr26'],
      dtype='|S7')])
```

Now I've looked through my code (the data is passed around through some functions before ending up in the `synced_query()` method) but I believe the data is parsed and passed correctly.

When I look at the docs the `q.sync()` method should only return a message returned from kdb and otherwise raise an exception.

So I'm basicly wondering why kdb is giving me such a strange answer. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to unpack the values in your python list `parameters`. Try:

```
def synced_query(self, database, query, parameters):
    print(self.connections[database].sync(query, *parameters))
```

(Notice the `*`)

As you have it currently, you are passing in one parameter (a list with 3 items) into your Q function, but you need pass in 3 parameters. A kdb Projection type is returned because you have called a function with fewer parameters than it is expecting.

Comment: Thanks mate, that solved the problem. My understanding was that I only needed it in the argument section (I had removed it just to see what would happen). Did not know about 'unpacking'. Thanks!

Comment: not too much out there for qpython queries - can I ask a related qs here pls? my output is a QLambda object. How do I unpack it? '<qpython.qtype.QLambda object at 0x000000003703A400>'