# qPython QProjection Issues instead of queried data

Tags: kdb, qpython

I tried writing a Q Code which will allow me to pass parameters however I am getting a results as Qprojection. I tried using

[qpython.sync() is returning a QProjection instead of the queried data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347252/qpython-sync-is-returning-a-qprojection-instead-of-the-queried-data)

but solution isn't working(new to Q/kdb world)
Any ideas on what exactly I should change?

```
q.sync(
'''{[x;y;z]select from quotestackevent where date within(x;y),sym=z}''', 
[np.datetime64('2018-04-14','D'), #start date
np.datetime64('2018-04-14','D'), #end date
np.string_('GBPUSD')])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Q/KDB the functional format is `{......}[x;y;z]`, with x y z being the arguments. If you have left a blank argument then the function becomes a projection.

qpython allows you to pass python arguments to a q function, with the format being `q.sync('{......}',x,y,z)`.

In your example the square brackets is causing the inputs to be passed as a single array to the function, resulting in a projection. This can be fixed by removing the square bracket.

`q.sync('{[x;y;z]select from quotestackevent where date within(x;y),sym=z}', np.datetime64('2018-04-14','D'), np.datetime64('2018-04-14','D'),  np.string_('GBPUSD'))`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.This works - Just wondering will there be any differences if I derive results in stages using temporary tables...something like this                         
    q.sync('{[x;y;z] t:select bid:avg bidPrices[;0],mid:0.5*(avg bidPrices[;0] + avg 
    offerPrices[;0]), ask:avg offerPrices[;0] 
    by datetime:date+time.second 
    from quotestackevent 
    where date = x,sym=y;
    n:select first datetime from t where mid > z;
    select from n}',np.datetime64('2018-04- 
    04','D'),np.string_('GBPUSD'),np.float32(1.3040),pandas=True)

Comment: Hi Shekar, I haven't tested but this all looks fine to me. As long as you are providing a valid kdb function, a correct number of arguments and appropriately typed inputs then it shoul all work.